# How does maven wildfly plugin locate the jboss application server (EAP)?

Tags: maven, wildfly

I have added the wildfly plugin and dependency on the POM.xml and it deploys normally, but i have not configured the plugin to identify any application server, how does it know the location of the application server? What if i had N application servers, how would the plugin know where to deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It deploys via the management API's. It attempts to connect by default to the known management port, 9990, on the localhost. You can override this with the plugin [configuration or properties](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/2.1.0.Beta1/deploy-mojo.html).

In it's simplest form you'd do something like:

```
mvn wildfly:deploy -Dwildfly.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dwildfly.port=10990
```

You could also set it up with different profiles in Maven if you deploy to several servers.

Comment: Thanks! This explains it.